# How to force "ln --symbolic" as --force does not work?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, symlink

I am trying to do a ln -symbolyc link for all the .* files.

The problem is that it works first time, but second time it fails, and it looks that --force does not work

This is the code:

```
ln --symbolic --relative --force ./websites/web1es/.* ./websites/webtable/
```

This is the error:

```
ln: ./websites/webtable/.: cannot overwrite directory
ln: './websites/web1es/..' and './websites/webtable/..' are the same file
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance for any clue!

Comment: Why do you have _bash_ and _zsh_ as tags? Please make up your mind which shell you are using. In particular in this case, the best answer may depend on the shell.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `.*` in the shell, that includes `.` and `..`.  If you specify a directory as the last argument, all the input files are linked into the destination directory with their same name as in the source directory.

As a result, your script is linking `./websites/web1es/..` to `./websites/webtable/..`.  Unfortunately, the latter exists and is the parent directory of both directories, so deleting it is not possible.  Moreover, as `ln` is telling you, the source and destination are the same file (or, in this case, directory), so even if `ln` could delete the destination, you'd experience data loss by doing so, so it's refusing.

Your solution should be to avoid handling `.` and `..`.  For example, you could write this:

```
find ./websites/web1es -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -print0 | \
     xargs -0 -I {} ln -srf {} ./website/webtable
```

`find` does not enumerate `.` and `..` here.

Comment: You mean I can't `ln -s * somename`? `:)`

Comment: You can `ln -s * somename` because `*` doesn't match `.` and `..`.  However, things are trickier with `.*` because it matches `.` and `..`.

Comment: I was being a bit funny, sorry. You would end up with everything linked to `somename`, and after the first link, the remainder would fail unless `-f` was given to overwrite the prior link `:)` You covered the actual solution well.